# Only a few of them mention a block having specific shape

Tags: gerunds, present-participles

> Myridon:
> There is a large number of definitions of "block" here:
> block - WordReference.com Dictionary of English
>
> Only a few of them mention a block ***having*** specific shape.

Source: https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/anvil-a-heavy-iron-block-on-which.3931328/#post-20125217

---

I'm not sure if "***having***" is a present participle or gerund.

Comment: Please edit your question (using the small "Edit" button under the question) to tell us what you already know about the difference between present participles and gerunds so we don't reinvent the wheel explaining it. Also, if you include the reason you want to identify this part of speech, it'll improve the quality of the answers you receive.

Comment: @gotube I know the difference between present participles and gerunds. However, I'm not sure what "***having***" is in that context.

Comment: In general there is **no** difference between gerunds and present participles.  Most modern grammars don't even use the terms.  They just talk about the "-ing" form of a verb.  So asking "is it a gerund or participle" is like asking if something is a "star" or a "sun".  Since stars are suns and the sun is a star.

Comment: @Aaaaaaassssss Please use the "Edit" button to fix your question, not just in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure this is a participle. A gerund is a verbal noun, and as a noun, it stands alone in the sentence. Additionally, a gerund *only functions as a noun*. Whereas participles function as a verb (with the help of auxiliaries), an adjective, an adverb, and a noun.

E.g. (gerund)

> **Walking** is a great form of exercise.

> I love **sleeping**.

E.g. (participle)

> I saw him sitting there.

> They had broken up their marriage.

In the context you gave, *having* is not a noun or does not act like one, so it has to be a participle. Or more simply, *having* describes the block having something.

An example of "having" be a gerund is:

> I'm thinking about **having** my driveway repaved.

Comment: In formal writing, the subject of the gerund should be in the possessive form.
Am I right in thinking that "a block ***having*** specific shape" shouldn't be changed to "a block's ***having*** specific shape"?

Comment: It should be "Only a few of them mentioned the block's having of a specific shape" @Aaaaaaassssss

Comment: I'm not sure if "Pretty" in "Pretty sure" in your reply means "very" or "fairly".

Comment: Pretty sure means quite sure @Aaaaaaassssss